# HTML/CSS - Do different text elements have inherently different sizing?

Tags: html, css

A problem I've been coming across is aligning text when they are within different elements. An example of this occurs here-

[image]

As you can see, the highlighted space for both texts is the same (the grey area on the right hand text), but the h1 element itself doesn't encompass this highlighted area on the right hand side, whilst the span on the left hand side DOES encompass it, resulting in a larger element (independent of the styling).

I don't know what causes this and it would be a huge help if someone could identify what the cause of this problem is.

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: using `line-height:1rem` you are using relative height to the element parents, that is why the line height its not the same.

Comment: Those elements are probably inheriting properties from something else, which either overrides what you have or does otherwise affect its' output. Share your code.

Comment: try to set the height to the fixed value (`50px` for instance) and you will see the difference - there will be no difference than in the line height

Comment: The line height is computed to be the same for both. What I've noticed though is that the Glyphs number is different for both. One is 10, the other is 12. I think this may be the cause, though I have no idea how to make them equal to one another. http://puu.sh/ktojq/9d3cd94284.png

Comment: The code (computed styles) is apparently too long to post. Alright.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should reset the default css of your elements http://cssreset.com/
This will remove any default margins and paddings from elements.
Then write a class in your style sheet and apply it to both elements. Don't use inline styles it's too confusing in the long run, and it makes your development more DRY. You should set your line-height to match the font-size like for like, ie 1rem to 1rem or 16px to 16px because depending on parent values 1rem may not equal 16px.